# Optimal conversion of BGRA buffer to AYUV

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, directx, sse2

I have a BGRA buffer, and need to convert it to AYUV format. The function below is working properly, but is very inefficient. I know I can make it marginally faster by moving some operations out of the inner loop, but I would really like to not do any of this manual bit manipulation.

Is there some sort of a DirectX way of doing this? Or a bitblt of some sort that can do the conversion on a GPU, etc? This is eating up too much cycles encoding movie clips we are generating.

This is a c++ project targeting Win10 Pro, written in VS2015, SS2

```
    bool Convert2YUV()
    {
        if (m_pBuffer == nullptr)
            return false;

        UINT uiPixelInd = 0, uiColInd = 0, uiRowInd = 0;
        short sR = 0, sG = 0, sB = 0;
        for (uiRowInd = 0; uiRowInd < m_uiHeight; uiRowInd++)
        {
            for (uiColInd = 0; uiColInd < m_uiStripeByteSize; uiColInd = uiColInd + 4)
            {
                uiPixelInd = uiRowInd * m_uiStripeByteSize + uiColInd;
                // Using local variables to avoid indexing operations every time
                // Buffer is assumed to be in A8-B8-G8-R8 format
                sR = m_pBuffer[uiPixelInd + 2];
                sG = m_pBuffer[uiPixelInd + 1];
                sB = m_pBuffer[uiPixelInd];

                // Conversion from BGRA color space to AYUV color space - Color sampling is 4:4:4 with 8 bits per component
                // Alpha is not participatig in operation since it is the same for BGRA and AYUV
                short sY = (( 66 * sR + 129 * sG +  25 * sB + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                short sU = ((-38 * sR -  74 * sG + 112 * sB + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                short sV = ((112 * sR -  94 * sG -  18 * sB + 128) >> 8) + 128;

                // Cannot do direct assignment to buffer since buffer is of the BYTE type, and during calculations, some overflow happens
                // Have to assign to short and then from short to BYTE
                // Components mus be in V8-U8-Y8-A8 order
                m_pBuffer[uiPixelInd + 2] = (BYTE)sY;
                m_pBuffer[uiPixelInd + 1] = (BYTE)sU;
                m_pBuffer[uiPixelInd]     = (BYTE)sV;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there are builtin facilities in the RGB->YUV direction in Windows. In the other direction there is the Direct2D YCbCr Effect for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/ycbcr-effect , so, you could write a custom Direct2D effect (using shaders) for your need.

Comment: You can check if the DirectX 11 video context capabilities would be suitable for your conversion, but you have to copy your BGRA data to a texture and copy it back from the YUV texture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11videocontext-videoprocessorblt

Comment: Apart from that you can also consider optimizing your algorithm by using SIMD instructions: MMX, SSE2 or even SSE3.

Comment: Thanks, will try this all

Comment: Hi, has your problem been solved? As far as I know，no such API can provide a direct conversion, maybe we can find the hardware accelerated to improve the performance.

Comment: @Strive Sun - no it has not been resolved. We are still jumping through a bunch of hoops to generate a frame for MP4.